# Deploy webapps and websockets in jetty

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, java-websocket

I have embedded Jetty into my application. I have one webapp and I successfully deployed that webapp in the Jetty. Now I got another requirement on Websockets. I followed this [link](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples/blob/master/javax.websocket-example/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/EventSocket.java) for deploying websockets in Jetty. After deploying the Websockets into my server the first webapp is not working (the home page is not opening). Here is the image

[image]

Here is the code (Its very hard to paste the whole code here. So I am pasting the webapp and websocket deployment code).

Webapp Deployment:

```
List<Handler> handlersList = new ArrayList<Handler>();
WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
webAppContext.setResourceBase(webApp.appDir);
webAppContext.setDescriptor(webApp.appDir + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");
webAppContext.setContextPath(webApp.contextPath);
webAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
// webAppContext.setWar(webApp.appDir);
webAppContext.setVirtualHosts(webApp.hostName);
handlersList.add(webAppContext);
argNewServer.setHandler(handlersList);
```

WebSocket Deployment:

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/echo");
argServer.setHandler(context);

// Initialize javax.websocket layer
ServerContainer wscontainer;
try {
    wscontainer = WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(context);
    // Add WebSocket endpoint to javax.websocket layer
    wscontainer.addEndpoint(WebSocketServer.class);
} catch (ServletException | DeploymentException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Exception while adding websocket endpoint: ", e);
}
```

WebSocketServer.java:

```
package com.tdg.chat;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/events/")
public class WebSocketServer {
    @OnOpen
    public void onWebSocketConnect(Session sess) {
        System.out.println("Socket Connected: " + sess);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onWebSocketText(Session argSession, String argMessage) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Received TEXT message: " + argMessage);
        argSession.getBasicRemote().sendText("From Server: ");
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onWebSocketClose(CloseReason reason) {
        System.out.println("Socket Closed: " + reason);
    }

    @OnError
    public void onWebSocketError(Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

If I include the aforementioned websocket code the actual webapp is not working, but the websocket code is working.

So how to deploy a webapp and websocket in one Jetty server?

**Updated:**

I tried to include the Websockets in the current webapp itself but I am getting the following exception.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:65) ~[javax-websocket-server-impl-9.3.6.v20151106.jar:9.3.6.v20151106]
>       at com.tdg.daemon.server.RiseServer.getWebappHandlers(RiseServer.java:122) ~[classes/:na]
>       at com.tdg.daemon.server.RiseServer.addWebApps(RiseServer.java:77) ~[classes/:na]
>       at com.tdg.daemon.server.RiseServer.init(RiseServer.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
>       at com.tdg.daemon.server.RiseServerConfiguration.build(RiseServerConfiguration.java:475) ~[classes/:na]
>       at com.tdg.daemon.server.launcher.DefaultTdgServerLauncher.start(DefaultTdgServerLauncher.java:78) [classes/:na]
>       at com.tdg.daemon.server.launcher.DefaultTdgServerLauncher.main(DefaultTdgServerLauncher.java:140) [classes/:na]
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:65)
>       at com.tdg.daemon.server.RiseServer.getWebappHandlers(RiseServer.java:122)
>       at com.tdg.daemon.server.RiseServer.addWebApps(RiseServer.java:77)
>       at com.tdg.daemon.server.RiseServer.init(RiseServer.java:59)
>       at com.tdg.daemon.server.RiseServerConfiguration.build(RiseServerConfiguration.java:475)
>       at com.tdg.daemon.server.launcher.DefaultTdgServerLauncher.start(DefaultTdgServerLauncher.java:78)
>       at com.tdg.daemon.server.launcher.DefaultTdgServerLauncher.main(DefaultTdgServerLauncher.java:140)
>   [] 12/02/2015 17:50:06.985 [main - ] INFO  c.t.d.s.l.DefaultTdgServerLauncher - RiseServer started on port 80 and 443.

Comment: What's your webapp's contextPath?  What's your server handler tree/order?  Why can't you have the websockets be part of the Webapp itself?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt My webapp's context path is /tdg. I tried to include the websockets in the same webapp itself but I am getting the following exception (can you please check the updated one because the exception is too long to paste here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext()` requires knowledge about the `Server` that it will be run under.

There's 2 ways to accomplish this, choose either approach before you call `WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext()`

1. Add the `ServletContextHandler` to the `Server` instance via its `Server.setHandler(Handler)` call before you attempt to configure the context. (the `ServletContextHandler` can be part of a larger `Handler` tree and this will work).  The mere act of calling `Server.setHandler(Handler)` will populate the `Server` reference for all of the `Handler` instances you have declared.  *(This is the recommended approach)*
2. Manually call `ServletContextHandler.setServer(server)` - but be careful to not swap out/change the `Server` instance you use later in `Server.setHandler(Handler)` call.  Also, once you do this, you cannot change things in the Server, such as the Thread Pool, Executors, Buffer Pools, Schedulers, etc. *(This is an undesirable, but functional, approach)*

Comment: I think I already implemented the same thing as you mentioned in the first point. Can you please have a look at my websocket code.? If I miss anything please let me know.?

Answer (score 0):

@Joakim Erdfelt, Its my mistake and I agree with your second point. What I did is, First I added my webapp handler to the server and then I added websocket handler to the server (Based on aforementioned example).

```
argNewServer.setHandler(webAppContext);
argNewServer.setHandler(context);
```

As you mentioned in the second point once if we set the handlers to the server we can't modify the things in the server. That's true, I modified my code like I added all my handlers in single shot. Then my webapp starts working and my websocket is also working. Here is the modified code

```
List<Handler> handlersList = new ArrayList<Handler>();
handlersList.add(webAppContext);
handlersList.add(context);
argNewServer.setHandler(handlersList);
```

Thank you you very much @Joakim Erdfelt.